# Elasticsearch full text search is too slow

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I use elasticsearch for full text search. When query text is short then it works quickly but when query text is big (about 10-15 words) then it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

May you provide more proper information, like

- a sample search-document or your Elasticsearch mapping
- how you query against your Elasticsearch-cluster /-node (API)
- a sample of your queries
- information on your configuration (nodes, shards, etc.)?

Cheers, Dominik